# Move ListView Scrollbar below GridViewColumnHeaders

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to figure out how to get the vertical ScrollBar in a ListView to clear the GridViewColumnHeaders. Can anyone give me some ideas of where to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 options...

1. Manually create the Header as a Grid on top of the ListView, and hide the ListView's header.
2. Rewrite the ListView's `ControlTemplate`
3. Use a `DataGrid` instead of a `ListView`

For #1, you'll want to create a DockPanel containing a Grid along the top for the Header, and the ListView taking up the remaining space. You'll have to specify how wide each column is going to be to line them up correctly, and be sure to hide the ListView headers.

For #2, you can use a tool such as Expression Blend to extra the default ControlTemplate for a ListView, and alter it so that the ScrollBar does not wrap the Header items.

For #3, simply switch to a DataGrid with `VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Auto`

My personal preference is #3. In fact, I don't think I have ever even used a ListView... :)